# How to use 3 different table relationship in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, foreign-keys

I am trying to implement a donut chart in Power BI using 3 different tables. There are two tables `users` and `groups` with their data and there's one `group_users` table for storing user's group activity. `group_users` table has foreign key for both the tables.

Now I want to create a visualization which can easily convey information from 3 of the tables into one. Unlike Tableau, I am not able to have multiple joins on single table as it gives relationship ambiguity issue. A Diagram of it is as shown below:

[image]

When I try to create group_users' and users' relationship active, it gives me "You can't create a direct active relationship between group_users and groups because that would introduce ambiguity between tables users and group_users. To make this relationship active, deactivate or delete one of the relationships between users and group_users first." as an error. **Note**, the connection is established to the Redshift cluster.

The donut chart should contain each group's count of users seperated by their age of users in different colors. And I should be able to filter each group's donut chart.

Please let me know, how should I create such visualization in Power BI?

Comment: Can you show some sample data from different tables? And also the Donut chart sample presentation you wants to achieve.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what result you want given what, ie exactly what "such visualization" is (or is a pictoral version of), or why you want it. PS BI "relationships" are not "relatipnships" in the sense of relational/ER FKs. (Which aren't anyway what FKs are; relation(ship)s/associations are what tables represent.) They are used to denote queries. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Replace your diagram with a screenshot of the actual relationships diagram from the Model pane in Power BI Desktop.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: groups -> users relationship sounds wrong. what columns is it based on? if you left the default setting to autogenerate relationships, you need to carefully review them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly without knowing foreign keys in users table for groups and group_members table.

Nonetheless, based on what I understand you want to achieve, you should connect groups table to group_members table on group_id (so that when you click on specific group_name in groups table it filters for members of specific group in group_members table). Then you need to connect group_members table to users table on some sort of account_id that I assume you have in both tables. Than right click on the relationship arrow between users and group_members, select preferences and change **Cross filter direction** to **Both**
[Set cross filter direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b4YI.png)

This should do the trick and give you the relationships that you need. You don't need relationship between users and groups tables.

Comment: Then how can i make sure the count of users is for filtered group? Thanks for this answer it worked partly.

Comment: If I understand your end goal correctly, you create measure that counts users (account_id or whatever the column name is). Than in the donut chart you put this measure in Values and age as Legend (probably will need to have some age range buckets created before, so it will be counted as category). Column group_name you put as filter in filter panel. Or am I misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is a relationship between all 3 of the tables.

[image: Power BI Model View]

1. Go to Model View (hi-lighted on left)
2. Check that there are joining fields between the tables (examples hi-lighted)
3. If there are joining fields, with no active join (denoted by the lines between the tables), drag the relevant field from table 1 over the relevant field in table 2 (same then for tables 2 and 3)
4. Return to the Report view. Field s from each table should be available for inclusion in the donut visual

Comment: I already have that relationship line in my Model View, but it shows as a dashed line. When I try to activate the dashed relationship, it shows me ."You can't create a direct active relationship between group_users and groups because that would introduce ambiguity between tables users and group_users. To make this relationship active, deactivate or delete one of the relationships between users and group_users first." as an error.

Answer (score 1):

First deactivate the relationship between users and groups, because that is where the ambiguity is coming from. When you have done that, you can activate the relationship from group_members to groups without an issue.

in the visualization, put the group name in the values, and the age in the detail (make sure you change the age to a text data type so that it appears as categories that are counted, rather than a value to summarized)